# Is dying while naked cheaper than dying with clothes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

While running a flash point my group decided to suicide instead of making the long lonley run back to the start point. We were wondering if dying naked was less expensive than wearing your gear.

Does the damage to gear from death apply only to equipped gear or to gear in your bags as well.

Comment: While I'm not able to do so at the moment, this should be fairly easy to test. Just take off your gear, note it's durability status, and go hug a Wampa.

Comment: Wampas need love too.

Comment: Dying while naked...? There has to be a joke in there somewhere

Comment: I must say, seeing this question on the stack exchange main page devoid of context made me do a double take.

Comment: Seeing this question on the stack exchange main page devoid of context made me think, "Yep, gaming's at it again."

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is another instance of "asking the wrong question". After completing a flash point, you can simply click on "Exit Instance" (it appears directly above your minimap) to be teleported out - no need to taste death.

That said, your primary question was worth investigating anyway.

I initially did not know the answer to this, so I made a new character to test it.

[image: The face of Gaming.SE]

*The face of Gaming.SE*

Characters start out with boots, pants, and chest items. These all started with full durability.

[image]

[image]

I immediately stowed the boots in my pack, and went off to make some friends. Friends who wanted to shoot me.

[image]

Thus acquainted, I took stock of my boots and my slacks.
[image]
[image]

Taking off my boots had spared them from a grisly fate! Huzzah!

So from this, I can state with certainty: **if you're trying to corpse-hop from place to place, strip down to your skivvies to save on repair bills.**

Comment: I didn't know about the Exit Instance button for the longest time!

Comment: Assuming you have enough inventory space to stash your gear ;)

Comment: Wow, excellent answer and thank you so much for doing such a thorough test. And, thanks for the tip about the exit instance, didn't know that was there.

Comment: Starter Characters have waived death costs?? That's really strange it showed durability wear. I could have sworn Death repair penalties were waved until you reach Level 10, So there should have been no repair penalties to dying with a brand new character in the test.

Comment: @Cistarii This was originally answered in the first month the game had been released, so I'm not surprised that things might have changed since then.